# Angular array displays last data in all views

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop, ionic3

I'm having problems on how to display the data for each topics on my cards.

HTML

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let topic of topicCluster" (click)="viewTopic(topic.slug)">
  <strong>{{topic?.number}}.&nbsp;{{topic?.name}}</strong>
</ion-item>
```

TS

```
  this.topicProvider.getClusters().subscribe(cluster => {
    this.clusters = cluster
    console.log(this.clusters)
    cluster.forEach(element => {
      const topicArr = []
      for (var key in element.topics){
        this.topicProvider.getTopic(key).subscribe(topic => {
        topicArr.push(topic)   
        })
      }
      this.topicCluster = topicArr       
      console.log(this.topicCluster)
    })
  })
```

Problem:

```
 1st Card: 
       14th Topic
       15th Topic
    ..
    5th Card: 
       14th Topic
       15th Topic
```

Should be:

```
1st Card: 
   14th Topic
   15th Topic
..
5th Card: 
   14th Topic
   15th Topic
```

This is the Data that I have [image]

Comment: What is the content of topicCluster? And give an example view to be obtained with that data

Comment: topicCluster gets the value of topicArr

Comment: @crystalthinker i add the "problem" and "should be" as view

Comment: Please mention JSon structure of topicArr/topicCluster , the last data screenshot you have given is not complete

Comment: Im having problem since it only display the last data from my loop

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your for loop as there is an asynsubscribe call and it will loose the context. The for loop will be looping and the last value of the key is passed to the async. You can do [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid this.

```
    let self = this;
    self.topicProvider.getClusters().subscribe(cluster => {
    self.clusters = cluster
    console.log(self.clusters);
    cluster.forEach(element => {
      const topicArr = []
      for (var key in element.topics){
        (function(keyData){
        self.topicProvider.getTopic(keyData).subscribe(topic => {
        topicArr.push(topic);
        })
        })(key);
      }
      self.topicCluster = topicArr       
      console.log(self.topicCluster)
    })
  })
```

Comment: it cannot access my provider. it returns undefined

Comment: have updated the code, with self for reference to the component 'this' reference

Comment: still it does the same. but it doesnt display on my view. im stuck

Comment: can you give a plunker/fiddle of the issue ?